# git: Clone repository, but keeping the original name?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-branch

I'm facing some issues with git: I need clone an repository, but git adds a ".git" at the end of the repository name. Originaly, the repo doesn't ends with ".git".

I'm cloning the repo with this command:
`git clone --mirror <user>@<server>:repository`

Both servers runs Ubuntu 14.04.1. There's a way to clone the original repository to the new server, keeping the same folder names and settings?

Comment: The last argument in your command should be the desired name of the directory. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone

Comment: Cool. Adding answer so you can accept. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last argument in your command should be the desired name of the directory. If you don't provide one, Git does its own thing.

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone